# How to get segments from a string?

Tags: c#, regex, xml

I have a string that contains all of my segment. It look like this:

```
var myString = "<seg_0 status=0>This is segment zero</seg_0><seg_1 status=1>This is segment one</seg_1><seg_2 status=0>This is segment two</seg_2>"
```

I want to get all segments from my string into an ArrayList like this:

```
{
 {"index":"0","status":"0","seg":"This is segment zero"},
 {"index":"1","status":"1","seg":"This is segment one"},
 {"index":"2","status":"0","seg":"This is segment two"}
}
```

How can I archive this using **Regex**?

Comment: You should try to solve the problem first, then come back for *specific* help. Include your current code, it's output, and a description of exactly where you are getting stuck.

Comment: `How can I archive this using Regex?` Hmm maybe by writing regular expression?

Comment: Yes. I want to write a regular expression.

Comment: So who keeps you from writing it?

Comment: Hmm. Maybe I will give it a shoot first.

Comment: By looks of it, it seems to be a XML string. Why do you want to use RegEx instead of LINQ to XML?

Comment: But all segments stay inside a string. Can LinQ query it? I need to start up with something like getting all of my segments and put them into an arraylist. So then I can do query.

Comment: Can you give me a sample?

Comment: It is not valid xml

Comment: I am giving it a shoot:

XslCompiledTransform objXslTrans = new XslCompiledTransform();
            objXslTrans.Load(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(myString)));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Regex extracting 3 groups:

```
 <seg_(\d+)\sstatus=(\d+)>(.*?)<\/seg_\1>
 Full match 0-44    `<seg_0 status=0>This is segment zero</seg_0>`
 Group 1.   5-6 `0` -> index
 Group 2.   14-15   `0` -> status
 Group 3.   16-36   `This is segment zero` ->segment text
```

to extract all matched items in string use `/<seg_(\d+)\sstatus=(\d+)>(.*?)<\/seg_\1>/g`

Comment: I am giving it a try.

Comment: I have a result now:

var myString = "<seg_0 status=0>This is segment zero</seg_0><seg_1 status=1>This is segment one</seg_1><seg_2 status=0>This is segment two</seg_2>";
            Regex pattern = new Regex(@"<seg_(\d+)\sstatus=(\d+)>(.*?)<\/seg_\1>");
            Match match = pattern.Match(myString);
            foreach(var item in match.Groups)
            {
                string value = item.ToString();
            }

Match contains only first segment. How can I get the rest segments?

Comment: Your solution is correct now. I am about to finish a sample code for my solutions. :D

Comment: Add `g` for globaly search : `/<seg_(\d+)\sstatus=(\d+)>(.*?)<\/seg_\1>/g`

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following *regex* to capture all the segments and make an array by replacing them with the captured groups:

```
input >>  <seg_0 status=0>This is segment zero</seg_0>
          <seg_1 status=1>This is segment one</seg_1>
          <seg_2 status=0>This is segment two</seg_2> 
regex >>  <seg_(\d+)[\s\w]+=(\d+)>([\w\s]+)<\/seg_\d+> 
replace with >>  {"index":"$1","status":"$2","seg":"$3"},
output >>  {"index":"0","status":"0","seg":"This is segment zero"},
           {"index":"1","status":"1","seg":"This is segment one"},
           {"index":"2","status":"0","seg":"This is segment two"},
```

see [demo / explanation](https://regex101.com/r/oRDrGs/1)

**C#** (possibly)

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class RegEx
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"<seg_(\d+)[\s\w]+=(\d+)>([\w\s]+)<\/seg_\d+>";
        string substitution = @"{""index"":""$1"",""status"":""$2"",""seg"":""$3""},";
        string input = @"<seg_0 status=0>This is segment zero</seg_0><seg_1 status=1>This is segment one</seg_1><seg_2 status=0>This is segment two</seg_2>";

        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
        string result = regex.Replace(input, substitution);
    }
}
```